# algebra simple question expression

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Dan is 5 years  older than his brother Joey. In 3 years, Dan will be twice as old as Joey. Which equation shows  a correct way of solving for Joeys age?

a) (J-5) + 3 = 2J + 3

b) (J-5) -3 = 2(J-3)

c) (J+5) + 3 = 2(J+3)

d) (J+5) - 3 = 2J - 3

My attempt:

I set up J+5 = D, and D + 3 = 2J but somehow couldnt match it to the above choices

Answer (score 1):

Your second equation should be $D+3=2(J+3)$ since Joey will be $3$ years older also.

Comment: then which of the choices does this correspond to above?

Comment: Substitute your first equation $J+5=D$ into the corrected second equation to find out.

Comment: i got c as the answer choice

Comment: That seems reasonable.

Comment: I notice that you've asked a few questions on this website, but you have never accepted any answers.  If you get helpful answers to a question, it is good etiquette to accept the best one.